# help with process method to find the length of a string

Tags: java

This is my song application

```
/* 
 *
 */

public class SongApp{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  Song song1 = new Song();
  song1.setsongLine("While my guitar gently weeps.");
  song1.display();
  song1.process();
  Song song2 = new Song();
  song2.setsongLine("Let it be");
  song2.display();
  }
}
```

And this is my support class

```
/* 
 *
 */

public class Song{
  // data field declaration
  private String songLine;


  /*sets the value of the data field songLine to input parameter value*/
  public void setsongLine(String songLine){      
    this.songLine = songLine;   
  } //end method  

 /*returns the value of the data field songLine */
 public String getsongLine(){      
    return songLine;      
 } //end method


  //method called process
  public String process(){
    int stringLength = songLine.length();
  }
  /*displays formatted songLine information to the console window */  
  public void display(){     
   System.out.println(songLine); 
   System.out.println("Length is :" + process());
  }
}
```

So my Question is using the process method i need to print out the length of songLine and then produce an output for e.g Length is: 9. but my process method doesnt seem to work so far

Comment: What have you already tried? What issues, specifically, did you encounter? This is not a real question that can be reliably answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a `String` from the `process()` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
    System.out.println(song1.process());
    ...
}
public String process(){
    return "Length is " + songLine.length();
}
```

....or you can make it `void`:

```
public void process(){
    System.out.println("Length is " + songLine.length());
}
```

Comment: i'll try the void sounds better cause i have to add charAt, toUpperCase in the same method, though i did try before and it gave me an error but i'll try again

Comment: now that i have charAt and want to return the last character of songLine should i use -1 as an index?

Comment: @Ron_ish: no, if you want to return the last character (as a string) you can use `return yourString.substring(yourString.length() - 1);` (if you use `yourString.charAt(yourString.length() - 1)` you get the last `char`)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to return something in the process method?

Comment: yes did try some stuff but kept saying can't return a void or must be string and couple of more errors

Comment: Either change the return type to int instead of String (so that you can do "return songLine.length()"), or convert the resulting int to a String (by doing: "return Integer.toString(songLine.length()))"

Answer (score 0):

Your process method is basically a noop. 
Either return the results or store it in a member variable.

If you want to return the string length from process do:

```
public Integer process() {
    return songLine.length();
}
```

Comment: i also need to put other stuff such as charAt, toUppercase in the same method, i just needed help for this one so i could figure out the rest